# How to Set or Execute a Command on the ViewModel from View in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to figure out how to get a reference to a command on the ViewModel from the Code Behind in a View without having a direct strongly typed reference.  You can do this in XAML so I feel like there has to be some simple equivalent in code.  I would prefer not to have to cheat by making a dummy object such as a button but at the moment I'll take anything.

Here is one example of something I tried:

```
Binding b = new Binding("SaveMessagesCommand");
b.Source = this.DataContext;
b.IsAsync = true;
Button myButton = new Button();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myButton, Button.CommandProperty, b);
object par = null;
myButton.Command.Execute(par);
```

The button really shouldn't be needed for this but I couldn't find anything else.  I could cheat even more I suppose by putting the button on the form, binding its command in XAML, hiding it, and then referencing it directly and Executing the command.  But I feel like I should be able to just say Execute This Command on this ViewModel.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just use reflection. WPF uses reflection internally and using WPF's methods won't make your work simpler.

Comment: How would I use reflection without a strong reference to the thing I'm reflecting?

Comment: `(this.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty("SaveMessagesCommand").GetValue(this.DataContext) as ICommand).Execute(parameter)` (not tested)

Comment: Sir, I have an almost unhealthy amount of affection for you right now!  That saves me from having to stay here all night working on this.  Thank you!  This will buy me the time to implement a more proper way of achieving the same outcome.

Comment: what am I looking at right now?!?!?!??!

Comment: @jrandomuser please don't do this to yourself.  Use something like [`EventToCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) or something.

Answer (score 1):

**The hack is the following:**
Create a command property on your view-model. Then attach a delegate (i.e. method handler) to the command when it's time for that command to be executed. You can then register an event on your code-behind that will ultimately invoke the view-model's command when the event is raised.

**The true solution is to implement an attached property** that will serve as a behavior based on one of your controls. When you register an attached property, you can provide a method handler for when the state of the attached property changes.

The following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) provides an overview of attached properties.